# How can I emit more values after emit an error?

Tags: rx-java

I have a `PublishSubject<String>` that emits `Article` from an id:

```
private final PublishSubject<String> inputArticle = PublishSubject.create();

public Observable<Article> getArticle() {
    return inputArticle.flatMap(getArticleById());
}

private Func1<String, Observable<Article>> getArticleById() {
    return new Func1<String, Observable<Article>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Article> call(String articleId) {
            return dataModel.getArticleById(articleId);
        }
    };
}
```

In another place, I emit values like this:

```
inputArticle.onNext("1234");
```

If I emit an article id that doesn't match with any article, `dataModel.getArticleById(id)` emits an error, and it's ok. But I want to keep emitting values after that error.

I'm implementing MVVM in Android. My view is bound to `public Observable<Article> getArticle()`. And when the user input an article id, `inputArticle.onNext(inputArticleId);` is called. So, is quite possible that id doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onErrorResumeNext` would work here, try something like this:

```
public Observable<Article> getArticle() {
    return inputArticle
        .flatMap(getArticleById())
        .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends Article>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<? extends Article> call(Throwable throwable) {
                // return either null or some Article object that indicates invalidity
                return Observable.just(null);
            }
        });
}
```

Find out more about error handling operators [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators).